# tcpdump tracing UDP packets

Tags: linux, tcpdump, snmp

On redhat linux box, I am trying to trace the **snmp** traps coming from **IP a.b.c.d**, as shown below:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump src host 142.125.248.36 and udp dst port 162 -w /home/user1/troubleshoot.pcap
```

and store the traces in `/home/user1/troubleshoot.pcap`.

Can this syntax go better to get more details about those **snmp** traps?

Answer (score 3):

You should use this packet type and filter rule:

```
-s 0 -T snmp "(dst port 162) or (src port 161) or (dst port 161) and (host 142.125.248.36)"

-s 0                grub entire packets content
-T type             packet type
"filter_rules"      filter rules
```

SNMP also uses port 161.

More at [tcpdump(8) man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump).

Comment: The `-s0` option is important too: it makes `tcpdump` grab the whole package and not just the protocol headers at the beginning of each package.

Comment: Thanks! I hurried with answer but I know about it. I will fixed it in answer.

Comment: I want to take/see that trap command(to reproduce) literally from wireshark trace. Can I see that with -s0?

Comment: With `-s0` you will see all trace from wireshark. If you want to trace from Wireshark directly, you may use this filter on chosen interface: `snmp and ((udp.dstport==162) or (udp.srcport==161) or (udp.dstport==161)) and (ip.addr==142.125.248.36)`.

Comment: Problem is, trap generated from device is not working but my validation trap with those varbinds, is working. Can the traces help me rebuild the exact snmp-trap command that device sends?